# Removing access privileges to backup while maintaining current setup

Tags: backup, chmod, access-control

I have a giant directory, and I am dealing with a backup.

I would like to store this backup in as safe of a way as possible.

One of the ways of doing that is removing rwx privileges through chmod.

Best would be if I could somehow lock the folder to anyone other than root.
I can do that by running chmod -R, but that effectively removes whatever access settings there were on all files beforehand. I don't want that for we may want to use this backup one day and then it would be good not to have changed whatever mod settings we have set within the folder.

So how can I best remove access privileges for all but root without permanently loosing whatever access setting was there before, within the folder?
Is there some 'lock folder' mechanism?

Comment: To make sure I understand your problem, which is it ? 1- the giant directory is what you want to copy for backup, the backup copy being in another place, or 2- you are using the giant directory as storage space for the backup copy of data from somewhere else.

Comment: Are you concerned with the safety of the backup procedure, or about the safety of the backup copy once it has been created ?

Comment: This copy of this giant directory is a part of the backup system. There are many instances of this folder stored in many different places. Not damaging whatever user privileges have been set within the folder is to me a part of having a high quality backup solution. I want to minimize the chances that anyone can break into the system and change anything, without marginalizing the quality of the backup.

Comment: So your problem is the following : you have an origional directory
A. You made with the backup system an identical copy B that is stored
in a partititon that cannot be write protected, and B still has the
permissions copied from A. But you want to prevent anyone from using
these permissions to modify the files in the directory B or change the
directory structure (which you call being safe). Is that correct, or
where do I start being wrong ? Do you want people to have read access
to directory B ?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the permissions on the directory where the backup is stored to 0700, owned by root:root. This will prevent anyone but root from accessing the files through normal means, and is trivially reversible when you restore the backup.

Alternatively, you can introduce a new directory level just above the root of the backup target location, which can be set to those same permissions. That way you won't touch any permissions on the backup at all.

Comment: What do you mean root:root. To me it's just root.

Comment: `user:group` is a common way of expressing "user $user, group $group". Most Unix-like systems call the group with ID 0 `root`, not to be confused with the *user* with ID 0 which is also called `root`. The two are distinct, but related.

Comment: This solution does not work, imho. Any process that already has access inside the directory, or has a link inside the directory, will be able to modify files while you are doing the backup procedure. Changing the location of the directory may not be a protection because some links may not be symbolic. And already running processes remain a problem.

Comment: @babou If you introduce a directory level solely for the purpose of restricting access, and set that to be owned by root and inaccessible by anyone else, then if a malicious process has access under it you are already hosed anyway. What Microsoft's Raymond Chen quite eloquently refers to as "being on the other side of the airtight hatchway".

Comment: @Michael Kjörling :  Well, yes ... both existing processes and hard links.